# Spring boot Eureka Client Health check got ClientHandlerException (Address already in use)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka

We are implementing microservice architecture using Spring boot

```
version: Finchley.M9
java:1.8
```

Everything was working perfectly, But Last day in UAT server I found a strange error in most of the Eureka client-services while health check. It just impacted some interprocess feign calls. It is occurring frequently. The exception is,

```
2019-01-21 17:46:21.567  INFO 5780 --- [tbeatExecutor-0] o.a.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient   : I/O exception (java.net.BindException) caught when connecting to {}->http://<IP>:8761: Address already in use: connect

2019-01-21 17:46:21.567  INFO 5780 --- [tbeatExecutor-0] o.a.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient   : Retrying connect to {}->http://<IP>:8761

2019-01-21 18:14:19.220 ERROR 5780 --- [tbeatExecutor-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error

com.sun.jersey.api.client.  : java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect
at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:123) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27) ~[eureka-client-1.8.7.jar!/:1.8.7]
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.put(WebResource.java:529) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.sendHeartBeat(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:102) ~[eureka-client-1.8.7.jar!/:1.8.7]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92) [eureka-client-1.8.7.jar!/:1.8.7]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.java:73) ~[eureka-client-1.8.7.jar!/:1.8.7]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89) [eureka-client-1.8.7.jar!/:1.8.7]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92) [eureka-client-1.8.7.jar!/:1.8.7]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:89) ~[eureka-client-1.8.7.jar!/:1.8.7]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89) [eureka-client-1.8.7.jar!/:1.8.7]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92) [eureka-client-1.8.7.jar!/:1.8.7]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:120) [eureka-client-1.8.7.jar!/:1.8.7]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89) [eureka-client-1.8.7.jar!/:1.8.7]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92) [eureka-client-1.8.7.jar!/:1.8.7]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) [eureka-client-1.8.7.jar!/:1.8.7]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89) [eureka-client-1.8.7.jar!/:1.8.7]
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.renew(DiscoveryClient.java:846) [eureka-client-1.8.7.jar!/:1.8.7]
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$HeartbeatThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1399) [eureka-client-1.8.7.jar!/:1.8.7]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_181]

 Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:134) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:118) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:173) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
... 26 common frames omitted
```

If we are getting 'connection refused' or 'cannot request to any known server' exceptions, which means the eureka server is down, But what is the reason behind this 'Address already in use' exception I found similar exception while starting two microservices in same port.

The eureka server yml configuration is given below,

```
 server:
   port: 8761
 spring:
   application:
   name: discovery-server

  eureka:
    instance:
      hostname: ${DISCOVERY_SERVICE_HOST:127.0.0.1}
    client:
      register-with-eureka: false
      fetch-registry: false
    server:
      wait-time-in-ms-when-sync-empty: 0

  logging:
    level:
      root: info
      org.app.discoveryserver: debug
    file: ${LOG_PATH}/${spring.application.name}.log
```

And the configuration in eureka client,

```
 #Config server config
   spring:
    cloud:
      config:
        discovery:
          enabled: true
          service-id: config-server
        retry:
         max-interval: 6000
         max-attempts: 100
         initial-interval: 10

     # eureka client config
       eureka:
          instance:
            hostname: ${SERVICE_RUNNING_HOST_NAME:127.0.0.1}
            lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds: 1
            lease-expiration-duration-in-seconds: 2
          client:
             serviceUrl:
               defaultZone: http://${DISCOVERY_SERVICE_HOST:127.0.0.1}:8761/eureka/
```

I checked the eureka server and found following exception

```
  2019-01-22 15:20:35.384 ERROR 8388 --- [get_localhost-5] c.n.e.cluster.ReplicationTaskProcessor   : It seems to be a socket read timeout exception, it will retry later. if it continues to happen and some eureka node occupied all the cpu time, you should set property 'eureka.server.peer-node-read-timeout-ms' to a bigger value


 com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
at com.netflix.eureka.cluster.DynamicGZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(DynamicGZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:48) ~[eureka-core-1.8.7.jar!/:1.8.7]
at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27) ~[eureka-client-1.8.7.jar!/:1.8.7]
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:570) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
at com.netflix.eureka.transport.JerseyReplicationClient.submitBatchUpdates(JerseyReplicationClient.java:116) ~[eureka-core-1.8.7.jar!/:1.8.7]
at com.netflix.eureka.cluster.ReplicationTaskProcessor.process(ReplicationTaskProcessor.java:80) ~[eureka-core-1.8.7.jar!/:1.8.7]
at com.netflix.eureka.util.batcher.TaskExecutors$BatchWorkerRunnable.run(TaskExecutors.java:187) [eureka-core-1.8.7.jar!/:1.8.7]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_181]

 Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:161) ~[httpcore-4.4.9.jar!/:4.4.9]
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:82) ~[httpcore-4.4.9.jar!/:4.4.9]
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:278) ~[httpcore-4.4.9.jar!/:4.4.9]
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259) ~[httpcore-4.4.9.jar!/:4.4.9]
at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:286) ~[httpcore-4.4.9.jar!/:4.4.9]
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:257) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:230) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273) ~[httpcore-4.4.9.jar!/:4.4.9]
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125) ~[httpcore-4.4.9.jar!/:4.4.9]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:684) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:486) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:118) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:173) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
... 10 common frames omitted
```

Note: All services are running as windows services in UAT server (Currently all microservices hosted in the same server).

If anyone in here faces the similar exception please let me know.

Comment: Are you starting two or more microservices on same port ?

Comment: No, All microservices except discovery and gateway are running on random ports

Comment: Are you running Eureka and Zuul /gatewayon same port ?

Comment: NO, Eureka on 8761 and Zuul on 8765